# C pthreads - Why is `sleep` interrupted by a thread cancellation request despite cancel state being disabled?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm currently learning C and POSIX APIs, in particular pthreads. I've encountered following situation which surprised me and seemed like it isn't supposed to be that way.
The `sleep` call inside a thread is being interrupted by a cancellation request from the main thread, despite cancel state set to disabled in that thread.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

static void *thread(void *arg)
{
    int oldstate;

    printf("other thread: started\n");

    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &oldstate);
    printf("other thread: started doing thing that can't be canceled\n");

    errno = 0;
    sleep(10);
    if (errno)
        perror("sleep");

    printf("other thread: finished doing thing that can't be canceled\n");
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, &oldstate);

    printf("other thread: exiting\n");

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thr;
    void *res;

    pthread_create(&thr, NULL, thread, NULL);
    printf("main: created other thread\n");

    printf("main: letting other thread work for 3 seconds...\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("main: canceling other thread\n");
    pthread_cancel(thr);

    printf("main: joining with other thread\n");
    res = NULL;
    pthread_join(thr, &res);
    if (res == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
        printf("main: canceled other thread\n");
    else
        printf("main: other thread result: %p\n", res);

    printf("main: exiting\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the following output from this program:

```
main: created other thread
main: letting other thread work for 3 seconds...
other thread: started
other thread: started doing thing that can't be canceled
main: canceling other thread
main: joining with other thread
other thread: finished doing thing that can't be canceled
other thread: exiting
main: canceled other thread
main: exiting
```

However, `sleep` gets interrupted and the output is as follows:

```
main: created other thread
main: letting other thread work for 3 seconds...
other thread: started
other thread: started doing thing that can't be canceled
main: canceling other thread
main: joining with other thread
sleep: Interrupted system call
other thread: finished doing thing that can't be canceled
other thread: exiting
main: canceled other thread
main: exiting
```

This just seems wrong. Cancellation request is not a signal, right? Then why does it cause `sleep` to be interrupted? I expected the code to execute as if instead of just `sleep(10)` there was a following code:

```c
// before `thread`:
static pthread_mutex_t sleep_mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t sleep_cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

static void *sleep_thread(void *arg)
{
    int sleep_for = *((int *) arg);

    sleep(sleep_for);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&sleep_cv);

    return NULL;
}

static void *thread(void *arg)
{
    // ...
    // instead of `sleep`:
    pthread_mutex_lock(&sleep_mut);
    pthread_t sleep_thr;
    int sleep_for = 10;
    pthread_create(&sleep_thr, NULL, sleep_thread, &sleep_for);
    pthread_cond_wait(&sleep_cv, &sleep_mut);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sleep_mut);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: [`pthread_cancel`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cancel.html): _"many implementations implement cancellation using a special signal"_ - I recommend exiting the thread by setting an atomic variable (or a condition variable) in the main thread that you check in inside the background thread instead of using `pthread_cancel`. That way the thread will always be "cancelled" in places where you accept it being cancelled.

Comment: oh, that's a shame... why did they decide that using a special signal is a good idea? what if I were doing a read or other important operation (more important than just sleeping)? There's no point to setting cancellation state then, is there? Or maybe there is and I just need to respect the fact that cancellation is implemented with signals and check for EINTR and retry? Or I should just forget about `pthread_cancel`/`pthread_setcancelstate` altogether...

Comment: There are some motivations in the _RATIONALE_ section. I've never used anything but atomics or condition variables myself so I haven't really investigated what benefits `pthread_cancel` may have.

Comment: gotcha. Yeah, I've read it, thanks for the link and your time!

Comment: *what if I were doing a read or other important operation (more important than just sleeping)?* Were you doing a [`read()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/read.html), and results were important, you'd handle short reads and interrupts: "`[EINTR]`
    The read operation was terminated due to the receipt of a signal, and no data was transferred." because, after all, `read()` only "attempt[s] to read `nbyte` bytes" and may "return a non-negative integer indicating the number of bytes actually read"  Because your process has no control over getting signals.

Comment: @felps321, rule number one of `pthread_cancel()` is *never call `pthread_cancel()`*.  I'm not sure it's even possible to use it in a way that is 100% safe, at least if you care at all about anything that the canceled thread may be doing / have done / be about to do.  (And if you *don't* care, then why are you running that thread at all?)  At minimum, it is extremely difficult to use.  `scanf()`, notorious as it is, is a walk in the park compared to `pthread_cancel()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am fully aware of EINTR and the return value of read. It's just that I'm reading "The Linux Programming Interface" and "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment", and none of the books had anything about signals in chapters about pthread_cancel, so that's why I was surprised when I saw that the behavior is just like with signals. But as it turns out, it actually is implemented with signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was pointed out in the comments, Linux actually does implement cancellation using a signal. That explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments point out, implementations may implement cancellation as a signal. On Linux, this appears to be the [primary implementation (see notes section)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html).

To work around this, you should use the return value of sleep(3) to resume sleeping if it's interrupted by a signal:

```
int sleep_for = 10;
while (sleep_for) {
    errno = 0;
    sleep_for = sleep(sleep_for);
    if (errno) {
        perror("sleep");
    }
}
```

Because of the imprecision of using seconds, it might also be better to directly use nanosleep(2) if the exact working time is important.